# This program isn't displaying the discount i made in it

Tags: java

This is a simple program , of a grocery  where I go to buy two items  , each has a price and a quantity.

This program multiply the first item price by it's quantity and the second too , then adds them together , but there is a condition where if the sum of these two items equal or more than 100 , there must be a discount on the total , which is 5%.

I wrote the program , but when I run it and the result of the two items is 100 , the program can't apply the discount , it gives me the following :-

> Please Enter The First Price
>
> 25
>
> Please enter The First Quantity
>
> 2
>
> Please Enter The Second Price
>
> 2
>
> Please enter The Second Quantity
>
> 25
>
> The Result Is =100
>
> The Discount Is = 0.0
>
> The Final Result Is = 100.0

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        byte p1,q1,p2,q2;
        short t1,t2,result = 0;
        float resu,disc,finaal;
        disc=5/100;
        resu=result*disc;

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please Enter The First Price");
        p1=s.nextByte();
        System.out.println("Please enter The First Quantity");
        q1=s.nextByte();
        System.out.println("Please Enter The Second Price");
        p2=s.nextByte();
        System.out.println("Please enter The Second Quantity");
        q2=s.nextByte();
        t1=(short) (p1*q1);
        t2=(short) (p2*q2);
        result=(short)  (t1+t2);
        System.out.println("The Result Is ="+result);
        if(result>=100)
        {
            finaal=result-resu;
            System.out.println("The Discount Is = "+resu);
            System.out.println("The Final Result Is = " + finaal);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `resu=result*disc;` is evaluated when `result` is 0 . So `resu` also yields 0.

Comment: `5/100` will always be 0, you essentially have `resu=0*0`

Comment: Once you have time [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) is a great resource

Comment: resu=result*disc; should be right after than result=(short)  (t1+t2);

Comment: Your discount is shown as zero because you print `resu`, which is zero. It is not updated when you update the value of `result`

Comment: What can i do to solve it ?

Comment: i did , nothing changed @erolkaya84

Comment: @MazenYosry and change disc=0.05f; please. Then voila

Answer (score 0):

You calculated `resu` before you calculated `result`.

Answer (score 0):

You calculate `resu` before `result`:

```
int t1,t2,result = 0;
float resu,disc,finaal;
disc=5/100;
resu=result*disc;
```

So `resu` is always 0, and no discount is applied.

You should calculate `resu` after result.

Also `disc` should be initialised to `0.05f` rather than `5/100`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int p1,q1,p2,q2;
        int t1,t2,result = 0;
        float resu,disc = 0.05f,finaal;

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please Enter The First Price");
        p1=s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter The First Quantity");
        q1=s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please Enter The Second Price");
        p2=s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter The Second Quantity");
        q2=s.nextInt();
        t1 = (p1*q1);
        t2= (p2*q2);
        result= (t1+t2);
        resu=result*disc;

        System.out.println("The Result Is ="+result);
        if(result>=100)
        {
            finaal=result-resu;
            System.out.println("The Discount Is = "+resu);
            System.out.println("The Final Result Is = " + finaal);
        }
    }
}
```

Test:

```
Please Enter The First Price
25
Please enter The First Quantity
2
Please Enter The Second Price
2
Please enter The Second Quantity
25
The Result Is =100
The Discount Is = 5.0
The Final Result Is = 95.0
```

Comment: Sorry , can i ask you a question ? , What Is "f" which you put in the declaration of disc=0.05f ? ... what is f ? @arizzle

Comment: @MazenYosry by default 0.05 is treated as a double, `f` tells the compiler it is a float.

Answer (score 0):

sure it gives 0 as result , look at line 8 and 9

```
short t1,t2,result = 0;
disc=5/100;
resu=result*disc;
```

so resu= (5/100 * 0) which is 0 
the correction will this (resu=result*disc;) should be excuted after (result=(short)  (t1+t2);) not before it

right code :

```
result=(short)  (t1+t2);
resu=result*disc;
```

result
 now 100

hope it helps